# Looking for clarification; How do I access a particular webservice with local files an Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, cors

It could be I have completely misunderstood how web services work.

So there's a webservice I want to access through a javascript file sitting in a folder on my desktop. The server I am trying to access has not set a CORS header, so I have some trouble just using regular ol' ajax.

And frankly I am not sure where to go from here.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"get",
    crossdomain: "true",
    url: "https://name", //actual name redacted from this question 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

A regular get like this will print the following in firefox's console.

```
  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ws.zooom.no/v1/channels. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

I got a hint from the task giver that I need to set the following in my "hosts file"

```
#127.0.0.1  www.domainname.com
```

Which confuses me. I have little to no experiences hosting anything, but does this hint that I need to maybe virtually host my "webpage" to access the webservice? It probably doesn't help to say I feel at a loss here.

Comment: Clarification: What lives in the folder on your desktop, the web service itself, or the JS file you access it via?

Comment: My personal JS file, the html and css file. The webservice itself is accesible through the internet on someone else's server

Comment: It's pretty unreasonable that they should expect you to muck about with host files, if that's an option at all. Have they flatly refused to issue the CORS header? Failing that, the usual way of accessing cross-domain web services is JSON-P, but that, too, requires the complicity and support of the web service. A final option would be to talk to the web server via a PHP proxy, which is not subject to JS-style cross-domain limtiations.

Comment: @Utkanos I asked them about setting a CORS header for me, and that's when i got the reply that I should set the "127.0.0.1  www.domainname.com" in my Hosts file. This is a front-end task, so yes, it feels weird that I should fiddle with server hosting, but I'm not that experienced so I weren't sure.

Comment: I'd definitely be looking to use a PHP proxy rather than set host files. Get a local server (don't run web files from desktop) and look into [PHP cURL](http://php.net/curl) - with literally 3-4 lines of code you can get a response from the web server with no cross-domain problems.

Comment: @Utkanos Okey, so I have now set up a local server with Apache through XAMPP. I have zero experience with PHP, and your link is a bit confusing to me. Could I tempt you to maybe write this out the steps in an answer? It seem like it should just be a install/import a library and then "3-4 lines of code"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115235/discussion-between-nachodawg-and-utkanos).

Answer (score 1):

So the bad news is that unless the 3rd party service either allows cross-domain requests (this is a configuration on that 3rd party server), or allows JSONP requests, you really have no option to access this service using a browser and javascript.

You could perhaps build your own service to proxy requests to that third party service.  This would give you control over domain, CORS, JSONP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Using something called "JSONP" that I had never heard of until now, i wrote a request like this

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: "https://DOMAINNAME.com",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

This somehow completely negated the CORS problems

Comment: Yeah I mentioned JSON-P in one of my comments but it requires the complicity of the web service. If they support JSON-P responses, then happy days.

Comment: Yes, the replies and help I got was enough to pull me through, just answered my question with a solution that worked for completions sake

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you've just discovered JSON-P, and want to learn more, I wrote a [comprehensive intro to it](https://web.archive.org/web/20130412164538/http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Mar/JSON-P-what-what-s-not-and-how-works-205) about a hundred years ago.